# How to simplify $a^{k \log_a{N} + 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Got confused on how to simplify
$a^{k\log_a{N} + 1}$

I understand I need to move $N$ down, e.g for $a^{k\log_a{N}}$ we would get $N^k$, but I got confused on what to do with $+1$... should it be $aN^k$?

Comment: @Workaholic yeah

Comment: If the $+1$ is out the $\log$, you are correct.

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to explicit parenteses, in order to avoid bad interpretations.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$a^{k\log_a N+1}=a^{k\log_a N}\cdot a^{1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$k\log_aN=\log_a(N^k)$ and so $$a^{k\log_aN+1}=a^{k\log_aN}a=a^{\log_a(N^k)}a=N^ka.$$